# Unable to correctly configure a specific User as an Apex Platform Event subscriber

Tags: apex, trigger, tooling-api, platform-event, subscriber

I'm following this [Configure the User and Batch Size for Your Platform Event Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm) documentation taking this [Tooling API REST option](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm?search_text=PlatformEventSubscriberConfig). The resulting `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` record can be queried via the Developer Console with "Tooling API" checked.

(The lack of Setup UI here adds a bit of confusion.)

But while the Apex trigger was running for the "Automated Process" user, it is now not running. I chose the SA User as the subscriber so plenty of privileges. Any known gotchas here or ways to check the configuration further?

A second related question is does the "Automated Process" user subscription that was added by the platform by default (shown below) need to be suspended to avoid duplicated handling?

[image: default subscription]

Comment: Note: It is important to stop and restart the platform event trigger for the configuration to be activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I'm now seeing it working with a backlog of bell notifications but only one email notification showing up.

Seems like the "Automated Process" user got automatically shut off even though it is presented as still 'Running".

So either I was doing something crazy (most likely) or there may be some delay before these change take effect.

Comment: Our team has also observed that the `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` settings do not go into effect immediately.  We've seen it take several hours before events show up as created by our specified user.